# Reading and saving features from/to file - OpenLayers

Tags: serialization, deserialization, openlayers

I'm going crazy. I am trying to reproduce an example from the OpenLayers 2.10 Beginners Guide, where I am trying to display features saved in a json file and add features on the map, and save them to file.

```
var map;    
function init(){
            map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
            var options = {numZoomLevels: 3}
            var floorplan = new OpenLayers.Layer.Image(
            'Floorplan Map',
            'temp_photos/sample-floor-plan.jpg',
            new OpenLayers.Bounds(-180, -88.759, 180, 88.759),
            new OpenLayers.Size(580, 288),
            options
        );
            var roomPolygonLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('Rooms', {
                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                    url: "myFloorPlanData.json", 
                    format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({})}),
                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed(), new OpenLayers.Strategy.Save()]
            });

            map.addLayers([floorplan, roomPolygonLayer]);
            map.zoomToMaxExtent();
            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.EditingToolbar(roomPolygonLayer));

            map.layers[1].onFeatureInsert = function(feature){
                alert("feature id: "+feature.id);
                alert("feature geometry: "+ feature.geometry);
            };
        }
```

So far, my map is displayed, I can draw vectors on the map, however it refuses to display the two points I have in my json file, and also save the new points I draw:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{}, "geometry":{"type":"Point", "coordinates":[5, 63]}},
    {"type":"Feature","properties":{}, "geometry":{"type":"Point", "coordinates":[-48, 27]}}
]
```

}

the json file is in the same folder as my jsp file, and I am running my project on a server

Comment: try replacing `new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({})` for this `new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()`

Comment: I removed the editing toolbar and the points displayed correctly... I assume you cant use the same vector layer to display points and draw points. However I am still working on saving the new features I am drawing, once I get it working I'll post the answer here. I'm playing with this example at the moment: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/vector-formats.html

Answer (score 0):

OpenLayers.Strategy.Save is not capable of modifying json file directly. It only works through a web service that implements WFS-T protocol.

You can install software that supports WFS-T, for example [Geoserver](http://geoserver.org). Then you can use OpenLayers.Strategy.Save in your OpenLayers application.

Another option is to create custom web service that will modify json file. You will then have create some sort of Save-button that will make call to your custom web service when clicked.

Comment: I already have thank you. I want to finish the full example before I post the solution :)